# How can I let the video start playing at particular position when after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

When after the page is loaded, I want to let the video start playing at 50 sec.
How can I code for that?

My current code is just like this.

```
<video id="video" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" name="media"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<button name="test" onclick="alert(Math.floor(document.getElementById('video').currentTime) + ' secs elapsed!');">How much time has already elapsed?</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) suggests you can just set the `video` element `currentTime = 50` when the page loads.

setting `currentTime` should seek to the value you set it to

Comment: Thanks. Now I found out that coding `document.getElementById('video').currentTime = 50` will solve it. But I don't know how to customize this in order to let it work once when after the page is loaded:(

Comment: @cat register some sort of event on the page load, there are lots of posts/tutorials on how to accomplish this online if using jquery `$(document).ready`

Comment: I tried to put `<script>document.getElementById('video').currentTime = 50;</script>` within `<head>` but it won't do any:(